# Lxml - No module name lxml.etree

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I am trying to install lxml and run into the following error after a successful pip-install to my venv:

```
ImportError: No module named lxml.etree
```

`etree.so` is clearly in my venv, along with `lxml.etree.h` and `lxml.etree_api.h` . I have even tried installing the newest versions of libxml2 and libslt to my venv.

When trying to build lxml from source instead I get this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c'
```

Thank you for the help.